# Checking if a geohash intersects another geohash

Tags: java, geospatial, geo

I have a problem where I need to check if a geohash falls into a list of other points with dynamic radiuses/boxes. What I am currently doing is getting ortb bid request messages that contain lat/lon and using redis to check what campaigns would match against the ortb's device lat/lon. This works fine if I query with a fixed radius. The problem is that I want to store the campaigns with dynamic radii dependending on population density.

**The Current implementation**

In 3.2 versions of redis you have the ability to store geohashes in a zset using the built in commands. This converts the lat/lon into a 52 bit geohash.

Using the redis zset functionality I can query the list of campaigns also passing in a radius. This will return me (0,n) campaigns that fall into the current radius.

**The Current implementation drawbacks**

The problem I have is that the campaigns have dynamic radii. So for example 1 campaign may have a 3 miles radius where another may have a 20 mile radius. Since I am required to pass in a single radius I simply pass 5 miles but this will exclude requests from the 20 mile radius.

**Potential Improved Implementation**

I was thinking about this problem but am not sure how to put it together. I think what would be a better solution would be to have a list of geohashes in a sorted set with different precision essentially creating a geo hash box for each entry. The problem now is that I am not 100% sure about how to go about putting this together or if it would work as I want it to. I am really looking for guidance if this would work and if anyone has put something together like this. I think I can accomplish this using a simple sorted set and then masking the bits down the precision of the entry in the sorted set. However I can see this being an issue when dealing with a large list of campaigns. Not exactly sure if it will work with multiple integers of different precision or how the O notation would work out on this one. I need it to be as fast as possible due to the fact that I am dealing with around 4+billion requests a day.

**Notes**

I hope I have done a decent job of the problem since it is a fairly complex problem to describe. I have also looked at quite a few libraries but I don't think they will solve the problem for me. I have started writing my own implementation but the complexity quickly makes my head hurt.

The original library that I investigated. Allows for single box query.

https://github.com/kungfoo/geohash-java

This one looks more promising but I wasn't sure if it will actually give the ability to search multiple boxes.

https://github.com/davidmoten/geo

Here is an outstanding overview of geohasing. Not sure why it is located at an IP but I am glad I found it.

http://23.239.12.206:8000/posts/2014-04-05-geohash-proximity-pt2.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try a weighted voronoi diagram and a point in polygon test. A simple and fast solution could be a bitmap with each cell of the weighted voronoi diagram has a color. Then simply check the color of the point.